# yii bootstrap + widget TbButtonColumn + widget TbButtonGroup

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

## yii bootstrap + widget TbButtonColumn + widget TbButtonGroup

Faced with such a problem:

Table is formed by the widget TbGridView from bootstrap (from yii-booster). In the column TbButtonColumn I form the "edit / delete, etc."

But one button I want to do with the effect of Split dropdowns
http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/components.html#buttonDropdowns

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'id'=>'customer-grid',
    'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'surname',
        'name',
        'middlename',
        'dateOfBirth',
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{add} {list} {update} {print_act}',
            'buttons'=>array
            (
                'add' => array
                (
                    'label'=>'Назначить прием',
                    'icon'=>'plus',
                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("reception/create", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                    'options'=>array(
                        'class'=>'btn btn-small',
                    ),
                ),
                'list' => array
                (
                    'label'=>'Список предоставленных услуг',
                    'icon'=>'list white',
                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("patient/update", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                    'options'=>array(
                        'class'=>'btn btn-small btn-info',
                    ),
                ),
                'update' => array
                (
                    'label'=>'Изменить данные Пациента',
                    'icon'=>'pencil white',
                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("customer/update", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                    'options'=>array(
                        'class'=>'btn btn-small btn-success',
                    ),
                ),
                'print_act' => array
                (
                    'label'=>'Печать акта выполненных работ',
                    'icon'=>'print',
                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("customer/printAct", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                    'options'=>array(
                        'class'=>'btn btn-small',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'htmlOptions'=>array(
                'style'=>'width: 220px',
            ),
        ) 
    ),
));
```

Comment: I haven't worked with TbGridView but I think that you can extend the TbGridView widget. Find the place where original author draws the buttons, then you can overwrite this function, to start the custom button widget. Input for this widget should be given from TbGridView options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've always found that when I need to render a complex element in a gridview (especially a widget) it's easier if you call a function from the controller. For example your gridview would have columns that are defined like this:

```
'columns'=>array(
    'surname',
    'name',
    'middlename',
    'dateOfBirth'
    ...
    array(
        'name'=>'fieldName',
        //call the function 'renderButtons' from the current controller
        'value'=>array($this,'renderButtons'),
    ),
 )
```

And then in your action would look something like this. This just renders the example widget from Yii-booster example page http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/components.html#buttonDropdowns:

Edit: This is also helpful because of the callback function renderButtons() accepts 2 parameters: $data and $row. You can use $data to access data from the gridview's data provider in order to dynamically render a widget.

```
public function renderButtons($data, $row) {
   $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonGroup', array(
      'size'=>'large',
      'type'=>'inverse', // '', 'primary', 'info', 'success', 'warning', 'danger' or 'inverse'
      'buttons'=>array(
         array('label'=>'Inverse', 'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Action', 'url'=>'#'),
            array('label'=>'Another action', 'url'=>'#'),
            array('label'=>'Something else', 'url'=>'#'),
            '---',
            array('label'=>'Separate link', 'url'=>'#'),
        )),
      ),
   ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by adding another column.  Both TbColumnButton abd TbButtonGroup are both widgets.  You can add a button group by

```
...
array(
    'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
),
array(
    'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonGroup',
    ...
),
```